# Dialog not shown in Android

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have some specific logic in which there is a need to wait 5 seconds before dismissing spinner and showing dialog message. Everything works but dialog message not shown. If i do the same thing without delay it works.
My code is:

```
public static void showMessageNotSentDialog(Activity inActivity)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(inActivity);                       
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.error);         

    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(R.string.error_sending_message);
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
        }

    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();      
    alertDialog.show();
}

public static void showDelayedErrorMessage(final Activity inActivity)
{

    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            com.test.classes.Spinner.hideSpinner();
            showMessageNotSentDialog(inActivity);

      }
      worker.schedule(task, com.test.classes.Spinner.TEXT_SPINNER_HIDEOUT_SEC, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Trying to show dialog from UI thread:

```
public static void showDelayedErrorMessage(final Activity inActivity)
{

    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            com.test.classes.Spinner.hideSpinner();

            Runnable messageTask = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    showMessageNotSentDialog(inActivity);
                }
              };
              inActivity.runOnUiThread(messageTask);
        }
      };

      worker.schedule(task, com.test.classes.Spinner.TEXT_SPINNER_HIDEOUT_SEC, TimeUnit.SECONDS);         
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use count down timer and no need to play with threads

```
    new CountDownTimer(5000,5000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
```

onfinish executes after 5 seconds

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), which can update the gui thread. Basically you could just post execute on the handler with delay, here is an example:

```
Handler guiHandler = new Handler();
Runnable showDialog = new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
     //put here the dialog creation
   }
}

postDelayed (showDialog ,5000); // Post for 5 seconds
```

Note that the creation of the Handler must be within the GUI thread, otherwise it won't work. and remember that the GUI can be manipulated by the main thread only.